# The type already contains a definition

Tags: c#

I got a problem in this program,

```
namespace WorkingWithXML
{
    public class information
    {
        private string Data1;
        private string Data2;
        private string Data3;

        public string Data1
        {
            get { return Data1; }
            set { Data1 = value; }
        }
        public string Data2
        {
            get { return Data2; }
            set { Data2 = value; }
        }
        public string Data3
        {
            get { return Data3; }
            set { Data3 = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

> The type 'WorkingWithXML.information' already contains a definition for 'data1'

can any one guess whats the error
thanks..!

Comment: The error message tells you what the error is.

Comment: _camelCase is the common naming convention for fields in a class. _data1, _data2, _data3. Properties are in Pascal Case (Upper Camel Case) like defined in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same name for a field and a property in the same class - two `Data1, Data2 Data3`. It is not allowed.

I'l suggest you swith the field names to `data1,data2,data3`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a field and a property with the same name. On a setter like this:

```
set { Data1 = value; }
```

The compiler can't tell if you're referring to the member variable or the property (which would be a recursive set and cause a stack overflow exception).

The normal approach is to name member variables differently. For example either `_Data1` or `m_Data1`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you got mistake in implementation properties, you should use backfields
or rewrite to auto properties

```
namespace WorkingWithXML
{
    public class information
    {
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
        public string Data3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```